# Set a RadioButtonFor() checked by default within a Foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, radio-button

I have a weird behavior using `@Html.RadioButtonFor` Extension Method. I am using a foreach loop to create a list of RadioButton and By ternary operator. I am trying to set the one who respect the condition to checked but It is always the last who is checked. I searched similars question but I am not sure to have found something. And I don't want to create/use a custom `RadioButtonList`.

Here my code in my **View**:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Entities)
        {
        <div>
                 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => item.Default, item.EntityId,
                       new { @checked = item.Default ? "checked" : "" })//item.Default is a bool and there is only one set to True 
        </div>
        }
```

But In my browser it is always the last created which is `checked` even if `item.Default` is `false`.
So is there something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `checked` attribute is present (no matter what it's actual value is), the browsers see the button as checked. This is HTML5 behavior. I'm guessing all radiobuttons have the `checked` attribute defined and the browser will select the last button to be the final selected one.

My solution is to create a custom RadioButtonFor extension method, which accepts a boolean for the checked-state and depending on the value add the checked attribute to the htmlAttributes dictionary. Something like so:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object value, object htmlAttributes, bool checkedState)
    {
        var htmlAttributeDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        if (checkedState)
        {
            htmlAttributeDictionary.Add("checked", "checked");
        }

        return htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, value, htmlAttributeDictionary);
    }
```

You can then use that method in your view (don't forget to add the namespace where you created the extension method and put it in the config) like so:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Entities)
    {
    <div>
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => item.Default, item.EntityId, new { /* other attributes go here */ }, item.Default)
    </div>
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The precedence of operators is causing the problem here; as equality comes before comparison, the phrase will be evaluated as

```
(@checked = item.Default) ? "checked" : ""
```

whereas you want it to be

```
@checked = (item.Default ? "checked" : "")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result. And Ternary Operator is not supposed to behave depending on the precedence, for what I know