# How can get selected radion button in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

I have three radio buttons and my field value type is **integer** like Maintenance for 3, 
Active for 1 and Inactive for 2.

```
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "3") Maintenance
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId,"1") Active
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "2") Inactive
```

i using above code then insert data properly but when my form open in edit mode then i have not get any radio button selected.

and i also used below code but not get success.

```
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "3", Model.StatusId == '3' ? new {Checked = "checked"} : null) Maintenance
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "1",Model.StatusId == '1' ? new {Checked = "checked"} : null) Active}
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "2",Model.StatusId == '2' ? new {Checked = "checked"} : null) Inactive
```

so how to get selected radio button in edit mode

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "2", Model.StatusId == '2' ? new {@Checked = "checked"} : '')
```

OR

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.StatusId, "2", Model.StatusId == '2' ? new {@Checked = "checked"} : null)
```

If above code is not worked then please provide your rendered html code of this radiobutton/input.

Answer (score 2):

My solution in post [Set a RadioButtonFor() checked by default within a Foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382612/set-a-radiobuttonfor-checked-by-default-within-a-foreach-loop/23383159#23383159) will work for you. Use the `Model.StatusId == '3'` comparison to determine the 'checked' value in the extension method.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below link may be help to you.

- [Checkbox And Radio Button Editor Templates In Mvc 4](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/06/checkbox-and-radio-button-editor.html)
- [MVC Radio Button Default Checked](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/12/mvc-radio-button-default-checked.html)
- [Radio Button Group In Mvc](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/12/radio-button-group-in-mvc.html)